# Strange LLDB error Xcode

Tags: xcode

I've made a huge project and suddenly when I was making it I got this annoying LLDB error. I get no error message other than LLDB and when I stop debugging and run the application in the simulator it works fine.

This is the left-side messages
self    AppDelegate *   0x1cd9e3c0
application UIApplication * 0x1cd9a940

Nothing else shown. I'm using only ARMV7 so that isn't the problem in my case :(.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: clean build and restart Xcode mainly solve problems.

Comment: Did both but still crashing :/, any other ideas?